# jmeter-maven-plugin - how to use plugins without download

Tags: java, maven, testing, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm using jmeter-maven-plugin to execute JMeter tests with maven. The JMeter project depends on some plugins which I need to include in the test run. Further, I want to include these plugin JAR files in the project directory, not to download them at runtime. How to do this with jmeter-maven-plugin?

Comment: Does this cover your scenario? https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath